# how can i push my localhost project to github

Tags: github, localhost

Hello I want to use github but I have no clue how to use it. I read the tutorial but I still can't figure it out.

What I want is that i can push my project from my xampp localhost to github.

How can I do that?

Thanks for responding

Comment: This could potentially be a lot of work.  Have you setup Git on your local computer?  You would need to configure Git by specifying GitHub as a remote repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new Repository : https://github.com/new

and

```
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/yourPseudo/repositoryName.git
git push -u origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use windows: You can install the following tool from [Github-for-Windows](https://desktop.github.com/). It is really easy to use and you can upload your local project easily with the tool set up.

Answer (score 0):

@bouffe Basically said all you need to say.

I find it easier to create a repo in github first, check the box for "add a readme" and then once you have a page, just do a git clone in your local environment. That way you can just type in `git clone https://github.com/yourPseudo/repositoryName.git` which you can copy and paste.

That saves time. Also, if you use VS code you don't even need to do the commit -m anymore. Just save your changes and then click on the dev tools on the left and it will add and commit all new files. Makes it much easier.

Make sure you do a `git checkout -b "dev"` once you set up a repo. NEVER CODE ON THE MASTER.